# Aligning text to the left & Right of a circle depending on the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I was wondering anyone knew a suitable way of aligning text on the right or left of a circle dependent on the data it holds.

At the moment I have this & it works:

```
//creating the circles & text together
 var node = svg.selectAll("a.node")
 .data(json)
 .enter().append("a")
 .attr("class", "node")
 ;

  //returning the shape & colors variable & linking it with the relevance in DB
node.append('path') 
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(circle))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")

   ;
//returning the names from the db
node.append("text")
   .text(function(d) { return d.Name; })
   .style("font-size", "8px")
   .style("font", "Arial")
   .attr('x',  function (d) { 

          if (d.Field === "Canda"&& d.Name.length > 40) {return -180 }
            else if (d.Field === "Canda") {return 9}
          else {return 2} 

        ;})
   .attr('y', 2);
```

But, due to my json text being different lengths - when I say '-140' the texts that are shorter aren't even close to the circle. Therefore, is there a dynamic way to have the text all the same distance from the circle no matter if the length varies?

EDIT: just added .length .. but that would still mean that I would need to do more if statements as the text would be varied lengths.

http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/66/

Comment: Any chance you could put this on jsfiddle for us to... fiddle with?

Comment: Hi @cmonkey I have put a example on jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/66/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution involving text-anchor:

```
force.on("tick", function() {

   // edit to include text-anchor
   text.attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
       if( d.Country ==="USA" ) { return "end" } 
       else { return "start" }
   } )
   // edit to change x starting point
   text.attr("x", function(d) {

           if (d.Country ==="USA") { 
                return d.x - 10;
           }
           else {  
               return d.x + 6; 
           } 
   })

   .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 4; });           

 node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```